# Trouble resizing JQuery modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, modal-dialog

CSS:

```
#mask {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9000;
    background-color: #000;
    display: none;          
}
#boxes .window {
    position: fixed;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}   
#boxes #dialog {
    background: #f2f2f2 url('App_Themes/prompt_panel_gradient.png') top left repeat-x;           
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <b>Testing modal window</b> |
        <a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>            
    </div>
    <div id="mask">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
e.preventDefault();
//Get the A tag
var id = $(this).attr('href');

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

//Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

//transition effect     
$('#mask').fadeIn(500);
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.9);

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
    $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);                

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(500);
});

//if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function(e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });

    $('#mask').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
    });
});

</script>
```

Everything works fine, the modal window opens with background image, link works fine, but the size is not 800x600 nor can I change the size of the modal window.  What am I missing?  Thanks

Comment: I'm confused on what your question is... http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/Mr5Qe/3/  This seems to work just fine.... the expected behavior (from what i read) is the 'dialog' div is 800X600

Comment: I am trying to size the modal window, yet failing.  The mask should be full browser screen and the modal window popup should be 800x600.  The #dialog and .window are declared as <div id=dialog class=window> yet the css for each has no effect on the size of the window popup.

Answer (score 0):

So, after looking through your code this is what I came up with... if this is what you were looking for you may want to look into jQuery selectors and how they work...

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/Mr5Qe/8/

JS:

```
$('a.close').click(function(e) {//Note this gets the 'a' with the class (dot notation) 'close'
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the A tag
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(this).parent().height();//this ('a' with 'close' class) parent (dialog div)
    var maskWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    console.log("Mask Height [" + maskHeight + "]");
    console.log("Mask Width [" + maskWidth + "]");

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({
        'width': maskWidth,
        'height': maskHeight
    });

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500);
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.9);

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
    $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(500);
});

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function(e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask, .window').hide();
});

$('#mask').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});
```

​
HTML

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <b>Testing modal window</b> |
        <a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>            
    </div>
    <div id="mask">
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#mask {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9000;
    background-color: #000;
    display: none;          
}
#boxes .window {
    position: fixed;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}   
#boxes #dialog {
    background: #f2f2f2 top left repeat-x;           
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}​
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that simply adding the width and height inside the div declaration in the html fixed the issue.  I'm still not certain why it had no affect when used in the css code.

code:

```
<div id="dialog" class="window" style="width:800px;height:600px;">
```

Comment: did you even look at the js fiddle i provided?  The dialog window is the correct size.